# Interpreting Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: linear-regression

Below are the results of two different linear regressions.  The first only has an N of 10 while the second has an N of 43.  The first has a very high association between the dependent variable and the independent variables overall (Adj R2 = 0.948, P = 0.003).  The second one only has one variable in the model with a significant association with the dependent variable and a lower overall association (Adj R2 = 0.436, P < 0.001).

> [image: 1st case]
>
> [image: 2nd Case]

I am trying to understand some of the reasons for these two sets of results.  The first seems spurious due to the small N.  I am still having trouble understanding how the second could have an adjusted R2 as high as it does considering only one variable has a significant association with the dependent.  What kinds of things might be going on here?

Comment: If the dependent variable is different you can not compare the R2.

Comment: The dependent variable is the same.  The study area is different though.

Comment: `R^2` for the second model is not that high imho... it only "explains" (or better covers) ~50% of the variance, right ?